# Playstation 3 on PC Monitor

Tags: ps3, monitor, hdmi

I tried to hook my Playstation 3 using HDMI to my monitors DVI port via an HDMI-to-DVI adapter. The monitor does not display anything. I connected the same display to my laptop via HDMI with the same adapter, and the display works properly.

Is there some PS3 setting I have to configure for this to work? On a different community, somebody claims using the same monitor and HDMI-to-DVI adapter strategy and it works perfectly. I own an [AOC e2236Vw Widescreen LCD Monitor](http://www.pcworld.com/product/1410465/aoc-e2236vw-widescreen-lcd-monitor.html), which supports HDCP, so this shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: Try holding down the PS3's power button for about 5 seconds. It should reset the AV settings.

Comment: What do you mean by the last sentence of your first paragraph? You plug your PS3 into your laptop's HDMI and your laptops own monitor displays the laptop screen? Or the PS3 is plugged into the laptop which is plugged into the monitor? I'm just confused as to what's going on in that setup..

Comment: Sorry about that. Initially The PS3 was hooked up to the monitor via hdmi+adapter. When nothing was displayed, I pulled the hdmi cable from the ps3 and plug that to my laptop to test that the adapter isn't the one that is faulty. And sure enough, my monitor works.

Comment: I can't answer because I don't have any experience with PS3, but this is very probably a **HDCP handshaking issue** as T.J.L says below. A lot of people use HDMI switches to combine multiple inputs to their TVs since daisy-chaining generally kills compliance. The PS3 is refusing to output a signal because the monitor does not respond during the handshake. This is because of the monitor *and* the DVI port being non-compliant.

Answer (score 1):

According to the stats for the [AOC e2236Vw Widescreen LCD Monitor on CNET](http://www.cnet.com/products/aoc-e2236vw-led-monitor-21-5/specs/), it does have [DVI-D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Connector) which is a pure digital connection. That explains why it works fine with your laptop, as HDMI supplies a digital signal, electrically identical to DVI-D.

However, despite your claims I see no indication that your display actually supports [HDCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection). It's an implicit part of the HDMI standard, but DVI predates HDMI, so there's no guarantee any DVI device has it. The fact that your monitor doesn't appear on the manufacturer's site, and that it includes VGA makes me think it's very old, and probably *doesn't* support HDCP.

There are devices that strip out the HDCP protection. Some do it deliberately to circumvent the standard, some do it accidentally because they're cheap and don't follow the standard. In either case, they're of questionable legality based on your location, so I won't recommend one.

Comment: A press release from the manufacture says that it supports HDCP: http://www.aocmonitorap.com/v2015/kr/news_display.php?id=127 (scroll down to the "Tech Spec & Product Details" section at the end of article)

Comment: @RossRidge: it says d-sub and HDMI (HDCP). The model in the question  does not have HDMI, so the press release is for a different model.

Comment: @Yorik The press release covers multiple monitors. If you **scroll down to the "Tech Spec & Product Details" section at the end of article** you'll find this: "Model Name: e2236Vw ... HDCP Compatible: Yes ... Input Connector: 15-pin D-Sub and DVI"

Comment: @RossRidge: hrm you are correct, sorry. I see in the manual that there is a DDC-CI setting. Wondering if this needs to be "on"

Comment: @Yorik It would be worth fiddling with. HDCP does use the DDC channel to perform authorization so the DDC-CI setting (off or on) could affect it.

Answer (score 0):

If you used a different cable before changing to HDMI you need to reset your PS3 display output options:

- Power up your PS3.
- Hold the power button untill you hear a single "beep", don't hold it after that or you will just power it off.
- Wait a few seconds.

Answer (score -1):

I would say your monitor does not support Digital DVI. Because your monitor has VGA, and VGA is purely analog. Though DVI supports also digital interface. HDMI is only digital, and a simple cable won't convert digital to analog.
Some monitors can get both analog and digital at DVI input, some others don't. I believe the last is your case.

So, like me and many others, you can use a converter to VGA, for example, that's compatible with your monitor.
For example:[here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/1080P-HDMI-Male-to-VGA-Female-Video-Converter-Adapter-Cable-for-PC-DVD-HDTV-TV-/141496183989?hash=item20f1d46cb5:g:mtMAAOSwstxVbWrh)

I have a similar one. You find a lot of chinese offers on ebay.

Comment: I'm confused. My laptop connects to my monitor's DVI via HDMI cable + HDMI to DVI adapter. Since the laptop sends out HDMI signal in digital, that means the cable and adapter is able to convert that to whatever the monitor supports.

But yeah, I think the option to replace the adapter to the one you suggested is something that our electronic store offers. If I don't figure this out, that would be my last resort.

Comment: Oh. Ok, that's new. And strange. If it's purely a cable it's impossbile to convert to analog. And your laptop is able to do this connection corectly... maybe the laptop is able to detect it's analog and converts the signal to analog, even on HDMI?! 

But to clear things out, what to you mean by "adapter"? You say you have an adapter ... But is it simply a hard-wired cable, or a cable with some kind circuit attached to it? Because that link I showed you, it has a circuit that converts digital to analog, it's not simply a cable.

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that. Since my monitor only has VGA and DVI, I can't connect the HDMI cable directly, so I use this HDMI to DVI adapter: http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00ZMVGTA2/ref=s9_simh_hd_bw_bT869f_p23_d0_i2?pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-2&pf_rd_r=1QKCZ6S4NEWHFN3NT0KT&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_p=663146887&pf_rd_i=430444031

Comment: Yeah, that looks like a simple hard-wired converter. Does not state anything about converting and/or processing data. But the fact that your laptop is working with that adapter, is indeed intriguing

Comment: Exactly! I also tried the hold the power button for 5 seconds to reset the ps3 unit, but same result. The reason I opted for the adapter is because its cheaper and somebody with the exact same setup pulled it off. The VGA adapter you suggested costs around $12-15 in our area. And I'm not sure if that setup will pose the same complication.

Comment: I don't think so. It should work. It really states "analog conversion" for VGA applications. But, I understand, it's your shot.